# Alterar os eixos de um histograma de dados para melhorar a visualização dos dados

Tags: pandas, csv, matplotlib

estou praticando um pouco de ciência de dados para um projeto da faculdade com as informações disponibilizadas sobre o COVID19 e daí estou tentando estimar por gráficos a distribuição das faixas etárias

porém quando consegui plotar o gráfico, notei que ele saiu muito espremido pelo texto que identifica as faixas etárias. Pensei que talvez virar os eixos ajudaria a visualizar melhor as informações sobre as idades.

Aceito outras sugestões também, caso eu virar os eixos não resulte em nada ou piore.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Talvez fique melhor inverter os eixos mesmo. Mas também dá pra deixar as barras mais largas, experimentando com o parâmetro `width` no comando `plt.bar()`.

Outra conveniência que você pode usar é que os DataFrames no pandas também têm um método .hist:

```py
df.hist(by=['faixa etária'])
```